# Missing Return Statement within While Loop w/no exits

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have a java method that is "missing a return statement." I have looked into this heavily, and know that the problem is most likely that the compiler found a path  within an 'if' function which doesn't offer a return statement. However, my while loop should be set up so that when a path within an 'if' function reaches an endpoint where it doesn't return anything, it ends up looping the entire method.

The overall goal of the method is for the user to type in a file that they want to output to, but if they choose one that exists and then choose not to overwrite it, the initial question asking for a new file name is reexecuted, until a new file is entered or an existing file is entered and the user agrees to overwrite it.

tl;dr
I receive a missing return statement error when I compile although I cannot find a path in which the loop would stop causing the method to end without returning a value. 
Here is my code, does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you very much

```
public static PrintStream getOutputPrintStream(Scanner console){
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        System.out.print("Enter output file: ");
        File outFile = new File(console.next());

        if (outFile.exists()) {
            System.out.print("The file " + outFile + " already exists, would you like to overwrite it? (y/n): ");
            String overwrite = console.next();
            overwrite = overwrite.toLowerCase();
            char decision = overwrite.charAt(0);
            if (decision == 'y') {
                try {
                    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(outFile);
                    done = true;
                    return output;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            try {
                PrintStream output = new PrintStream(outFile);
                done = true;
                return output;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                        System.exit(1);
            }
        }          
    }    
}
```

Comment: _does anyone know how to fix it?_ fix it what? Be more specific and ask a clear question.

Comment: Fix the problem that I receive a missing return statement error when I compile although I cannot find a path in which the loop would stop without returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop condition, you wrote,

```
while (done = false)
```

which is wrong, as `=` means [assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operation. You need comparison `==`, so rewrite it to:

Ugly approach

```
while (done == false)
```

Good approach

```
while (!done)
```

However, you are getting error

> This method must return something error

because your method `return` nothing if your while loop block is not going to execute! Logically its not possible (as `done` is `false`), but compiler will not going to understand the logic and raise error.

The variable `done` actually has no impact on you code as you immediately return from your function after `done = true`. Note that, a **`return` statement causes execution to leave the current subroutine**. So you can just use an infinite loop, like:

```
while(true)
```

Then you no need to add return statement outside the loop.

Comment: I appreciate this tip, but unfortunately I still receive the same error as before

Comment: I added more information about the `return` _error_.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in the `done` variable, because after setting `done = true`, you immediately `return`. You might as well do `while(true)`. That will solve the missing return statement problem as the compiler will be able to see there is no way to end up below the `while` loop.

At the moment it is possible to end up below the `while` loop as you wrote `while (done = false)` rather than `while (done == false)` (the first one *makes* `done` false). However even if you change this to `while (done == false)` or `while (!done)` you will still get the compiler error because the compiler is not sophisticated enough to reason that `done` will never be `true` when the condition is checked.

Comment: Not a problem. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile if there is a way for the code to run but never hit a return value (i.e. In the while loop if outFile.exists() is true but 'decision' doesn't equal 'y'). The compiler isn't smart enough to say "oh, but it's in a while loop and will eventually return once the condition is met".

For your specific example, adding

> return null;

after the while loop should make it compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static PrintStream getOutputPrintStream(Scanner console) {
        boolean done = false;
        PrintStream output = null;
        while (!done) {
            System.out.print("Enter output file: ");
            File outFile = new File(console.next());

            if (outFile.exists()) {
            // if file exixts
                  System.out.print("The file " + outFile + " already exists, would you like to overwrite it? (y/n): ");
                  char decision = console.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
                  if (decision == 'y') {
                     done = true;
                      output = createStream(outFile);
                   }
             } else {
            // if file does not exist
                done = true;
                output = createStream(outFile);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

static PrintStream createStream(File outFile) {
    PrintStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new PrintStream(outFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```